# How to detect shutdown triggered on Linux via dbus

Tags: linux, service, embedded-linux, systemd

I need to perform some task before system will be shut down. I can't do it in class destructor because my service can be stopped not only because of shut down

My service already uses dbus to communicate to other services in the system, so I'd prefer to have  some dbus signal that will notify about system shutdown

[linux](/questions/tagged/linux) [embedded](/questions/tagged/embedded) [systemd-service](/questions/tagged/systemd-service)

I thought to do the task in destructor, but the context of destructor doesn't fit - I need to perform asynchronous task.

I expect some dbus signal to be able to subscribe on it

Comment: I guess a web search was not an option? https://askubuntu.com/questions/416299/execute-command-before-shutdown-reboot https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48973/execute-a-command-before-shutdown

Comment: @Robert this article is about starting some service on shutdown. But as I stated in my question I need some event to catch inside running program. And yes, I did research before asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the systemd-logind `Inhibit()` API via D-Bus to obtain a `delay`-type inhibitor. You'll receive a file descriptor as part of the call result, so make sure your D-Bus bindings support that.

Shutdowns initiated by users through systemd-logind will broadcast a `PrepareForSleep` signal via D-Bus, and the actual shutdown will be delayed until you close() the previously received file descriptor (although only up to a few seconds).

See the [xss-lock](https://github.com/Emantor/xss-lock/blob/62d9ac85ca25862615275dd70f93d2d20f454e31/src/xss-lock.c#L250-L327) project for an example.